# Updating and appending in D3 efficiently

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, updates, label

At the minute I'm having an issue wrapping my head around some of D3's syntax.

I have a pie chart working perfectly fine , it takes data from a database and updates chart with it.(I have left out all the database retrieving code and have just put the fundamental d3 code in the JSFiddle). However I think structure of my code and in particular the labels are somewhat coded inefficiently.

Here is the JSFiddle link.

http://jsfiddle.net/PW49y/

```
 var label_group = svg.append("svg:g")
        .attr("class", "lblGroup")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + +"," + +")");

    var center_group = svg.append("svg:g")
        .attr("class", "ctrGroup")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2) + "," + ")");

    // CENTER LABEL
    var pieLabel = center_group.append("svg:text")
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("class", "midLabel")
        .text(selectCounty + selectYear);

    var sliceLabel = label_group.selectAll("text.value")
        .data(pie(data))
        .attr("dy", 21)
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle") // text-align: right



    sliceLabel.enter().append("svg:text")
        .attr("class", "ctrGroup")
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
    })
        .attr("dy", 21)
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle").text(function (d, i) {
        return data[i].worker_numbers;
    })
```

Here is my update function ,  bear in mind that this does work but I feel like the way I have it now misses the point of the advantages d3 has for updating data.

```
 function change(data) {


            pie.value(function (d, i) {
                console.log(data[i].worker_numbers);
                return parseInt(data[i].worker_numbers);
            }); // change the value function
            path = path.data(pie); // compute the new angles
            path.transition().ease("elastic").duration(1500).attrTween("d", arcTween);
            // redraw the arcs


            sliceLabel.attr("transform", function (d) {
                return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
            })

                .text(function (d, i) {
                return data[i].worker_numbers;
            });
            sliceLabel.data(pie(data))
                .transition()
                .duration(500)
                .attr("transform", function (d) {
                return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
            });
            arcs.append("svg:text")
                .data(pie(data))
                .transition()
                .duration(500)
                .attr("transform", function (d) {
                return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
            });

        }
```

I feel like I have declared too many label variables and thus the way my graph updates is extremely inefficient. Should these label variables be attached the one variable? Then the updating would be a lot cleaner. However when I attempt to separate the label variables I seem to make a mess out of it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't work for me (various things not defined). The general structure of your code doesn't look too bad though and I don't see anything where it would be particularly inefficient.

Comment: This belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/